# jquery $.ajax: pass additional argument to 'success' callback

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using $.ajax to post data to the server. However I want to pass an additional parameter to the 'success' callback to tell the callback function the id of the HTML element the response is for.

It is possible? Like:

```
success_cb(data, elementid)
{
    (update the elementid with the server returned data)
}

$.ajax({
    ...
    success:success_cb(elementid)
});
```

Comment: The best workaround would be to actually use OOP, instead of passing IDs to elements around. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
function postForElement(elementId){
  $.post('/foo',someValues,function(data){
    $(elementId).html("The server returned: "+data);
  },'json');
}
```

By declaring the function literal in the same scope as the `elementId` local variable, the function becomes a *closure* that has access to that local variable. (Or some might say it only becomes a *closure* when the function literal also references the non-global variable that is not defined in its scope. That's just bandying with words.)

Answer (score 25):

It is possible. Try something like:

```
function success_cb(data, elementid)
{
    (update the elementid with the server returned data)
}

$.ajax({
    ...
    success:function(data){ success_cb(data, elementid); }
});
```

Comment: This (wrapping the callback in an anon function) is such a straightforward answer I can't believe I didn't think of it immediately.  :-)

Comment: this worked for me as well, but wondering... know it's been a long time, can you explain why it needs to be this way? like... why can't you do `success: function(data, elementid) {}` (i realize that there are status codes and such, so realistically the question is why can't you do `success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR, elementid) {}`)

Answer (score 1):

This might be a late post, but there is another option that worked for me.

On the Ajax object I added more variables, for example **variableNeeded**:

```
 $.ajax({
     url:"url.php",
     method:"post",
     variableNeeded:"ABC123",
     dataType:"json",
     error:function(){
          // manage error           
     },
     success:function(json,status,xlr){
          console.log(this.variableNeeded);
          // use variable as needed.
     }
});
```

Because is part of the object it will be available inside the success function by using **this** ex: **this.variableNeeded**